# in Fscrawler is it possible to derive index name from subfolder name?

Tags: fscrawler

I have a folder with several hundred sub folders and would like to index by these sub folder names...That is after running fscrawler I would like to have several hundred different indices...The default is one index (e.g."job_name") for all the sub directories...Is it possible to create indexes for each individual sub folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options I can think of:

- One job per folder
- Using an ingest pipeline where you can overwrite [the index name](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html#access-metadata-fields) with a [set processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/set-processor.html).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the set processor I did it using aliases in python where output is a list of the folder names I derived from _source.path.virtual:

```
for x in output:
  es.indices.update_aliases({
  actions": [
  { "add":    { "index": 'job_old', "alias": x,"filter":{"regexp":{"path.virtual.keyword":"/"+x+".*"}}}}
    
      ]
    })
```

The convert each alias to custom index.....